# Convert List<KeyPoint> to MatofKeypoints

Tags: java, android, opencv

So I am working on image recognition with Java and OpenCV, but I am stuck trying to convert the Arraylist back into a MatOfKeyPoint.

```
List<KeyPoint> newList = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>(points.subList(0, 500));
```

So I need to convert the newList back to a MatofKeyPoint. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatOfKeyPoint has a `fromList` method

```
MatOfKeyPoint kp = new MatOfKeyPoint();
kp.fromList(newList);
```

for stuff like this, be sure to have a peek at the relevant [javadocs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/MatOfKeyPoint.html) :)